# Equilibrium for the synthesis of methanol

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, equilibrium, phase

> Liquid methanol is obtained with carbon monoxide gas and hydrogen gas in a reactor at $\pu{300 °C}$ and $\pu{250 atm}.$ $K_p = \pu{9.28E-3}.$ Find $K_c.$

With only these data, do I have to use the following equilibrium for the calculations

$$\ce{CO(g) + 2 H2(g) <=> CH3OH(l)},$$

or do I have to suppose first methanol is obtained as a gas and then liquified:

$$\ce{CO(g) + 2 H2(g) <=> CH3OH(g)}?$$

Comment: To find out, it suffices to know the state of methanol under the reaction conditions: have you looked for it?

Comment: Yes, I saw in a phase diagram of methanol that under these conditions it is a supercritic fluid (hybrid between gas an liquid...)

Comment: Carbon monoxide is CO. Further more, equations are not balanced, unless you managed conversion O -> 2 H

Comment: Yes, sorry for the mistake

Comment: This question will be completely impossible to answer unless the text matches the chemical equations. are you talking about the reaction of carbon *monoxide* or *dioxide*?

Comment: methanol critical temperature is [240.2 deg C](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/methanol-methyl-alcohol-properties-CH3OH-d_2031.html), so methanol cannot be liquid at 300 deg C at any pressure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that under the given conditions, methanol cannot exist in the liquid state, however since you are *given* in the problem that methanol is obtained in liquid state, you will only consider the equilibrium (for problem solving purpose)

$$\ce{CO(g) + 2 H2(g) <=> CH3OH(l)}$$

And since $K_p$ is related to $K_c$ by the relation

$$K_p = K_c(RT)^{\Delta n_\mathrm{g}},$$ where $\Delta n_\mathrm{g}$ represents the change in the number of moles of gaseous species, so here $\Delta n_\mathrm{g} = -3,$ Therefore $K_\mathrm{c}=K_\mathrm{p}(RT)^3=9.28\times 10^{-3}\times (300 \times 0.0821)^3 \approx \pu{138.65 atm^3 L^3 mol^-3}$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119933/discussion-on-answer-by-light-yagami-equilibrium-for-the-synthesis-of-methanol). (Since I have this comment here, pardon me for adding a link to the newly redesigned [FAQ: How can I format math/chemistry expressions on Chemistry Stack Exchange?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/86/16683), as it teaches you how to use `\ce{...}` and `\pu{...}` correctly.)

Comment: Hm, OTOH, not all comments are discussion.